# Image segmentation using k-means

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, k-means

I 'm trying to use k-means algorithm for an image segmentation task . The problem is that my program does not segment the image.
Would you please help me to find the error in my code ?

In fact , I have fixed the number of clusters to 32.
I have used the following data structures:

- 3 arrays bleu,vert,rouge to store RGB values for each pixel
- 3 arrays cluster_bleu,cluster_rouge,cluster_vert to store RGB value for each cluster
- groupe[i,0]=k maps each pixel i to cluster k

  ```
  import cv2

  import numpy

  import random
  def main():
      MAX_LARGEUR = 400
      MAX_HAUTEUR = 400

      K = 32 #Le fameux parametre K de l'algorithme
      imagecolor = cv2.imread('perr.jpg')


      if imagecolor.shape[0] > MAX_LARGEUR or imagecolor.shape[1] > MAX_HAUTEUR:
          factor1 = float(MAX_LARGEUR) / imagecolor.shape[0]
          factor2 = float(MAX_HAUTEUR) / imagecolor.shape[1]
          factor = min(factor1, factor2)
          imagecolor = cv2.resize(imagecolor, None, fx=factor, fy=factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


      nb_pixels = imagecolor.shape[0] * imagecolor.shape[1]

      bleu = imagecolor[:, :, 0].reshape(nb_pixels, 1)
      vert = imagecolor[:, :, 1].reshape(nb_pixels, 1)
      rouge = imagecolor[:, :, 2].reshape(nb_pixels, 1)


      cluster_bleu = numpy.zeros(K)
      cluster_vert = numpy.zeros(K)
      cluster_rouge = numpy.zeros(K)

      groupe = numpy.zeros((nb_pixels, 1)) 

      for i in range(0,K):
          groupe[i,0]=i

      for i in range(K,nb_pixels):
          groupe[i,0]=random.randint(0, K-1)


      condition =False




      def etape1(indices,i):
      s=indices.size
      rouge_s=0
      vert_s=0
      bleu_s=0
      #calcul de barycentre des points
      if s==0:
          cluster_rouge[i]=0  
          cluster_vert[i]=0
          cluster_bleu[i]=0


      if s >=1:
          for j in range(0,s):
              rouge_s=rouge_s+rouge[indices[j]]
              vert_s=vert_s+vert[indices[j]]
              bleu_s=bleu_s+bleu[indices[j]]

          #mise  jour des clusters 

          cluster_rouge[i]=rouge_s/s  
          cluster_vert[i]=vert_s/s
          cluster_bleu[i]=bleu_s/s        


      iteration=0
      oldGroupe = numpy.copy(groupe)
      while(condition==False) :


      for i in range(0,K):

          indices=numpy.where(groupe==i)[0]
          etape1(indices,i)



      for i in range(0,nb_pixels):
          minimum=10000;
          dist=0;
          index=-1;
          for j in range(0,K):
               dist=(cluster_rouge[j]-rouge[i])**2+(cluster_vert[j]-vert[i])**2+(cluster_bleu[j]-bleu[i])**2;
               if(dist<=minimum):
                  minimum=dist;
                  index=j;



          groupe[i,0]=index;



      condition=numpy.all(groupe==oldGroupe)

      oldGroupe = numpy.copy(groupe)  


      groupe=numpy.reshape(groupe, (imagecolor.shape[0], imagecolor.shape[1]))




      for i in range(0, imagecolor.shape[0]):
          for j in range(0, imagecolor.shape[1]):
              imagecolor[i,j,0] = (cluster_bleu[groupe[i,j]])
              imagecolor[i,j,1] = (cluster_vert[groupe[i,j]])
              imagecolor[i,j,2] = (cluster_rouge[groupe[i,j]])

      cv2.namedWindow("sortie")
      cv2.imshow("sortie", imagecolor)
      key = cv2.waitKey(0)
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```

Comment: Your code formatting could use a little help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is assignment `oldGroupe=groupe;` which doesn't copy an array, but creates reference with different name (`oldGroupe`), that points to the same data as `groupe`. Thus, when you change `groupe` you also change `oldGroupe`, and `condition` is always True.

What you want is to create a copy of data in `groupe` with `oldGroupe = numpy.copy(groupe)`.

Comment: I have modify my code as you said and k-means converged .But , the segmentation  failed .

Comment: Please, add another question asking, why segmentation doesn't work. In the question, please, explain, what do you mean by "segmentation doesn't work". To illustrate the point you may attach two images: the input for segmentation and segmentation result